# Sprite Kit: change backgroundcolor with ColorizeWithColor

Tags: sprite-kit

Is there a way to change a scene's background color gradually, instead of it swithcing colors at once?

In my scene, I have a button that sets the background color to a different color than the color that is called in the initial creation of the scene, simply like so:

```
-(void) newBackgroundColor
{
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blackColor];
}
```

However, (of course) this switches the color from my initial color to black instantly whereas I would like it to change much the same like nodes do using `colorizeWithColor:` where two colors 'fade' from one to another. My guess is I would need to implement an `SKAction` before setting the new color, but the `backgroundColor` property does not seem to support the colorize action.

Is this possible? I have not been able to find out how so far.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share me a demo of this some where , so that i could debug it

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but well, all my button really does is call the `newbackgroundColor` method (I've edited my question with the method), which works as expected. It is, however, not what I want to happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action will only work on an actual `SKSpriteNode` object - for example, add a white, background-sized image to your scene to act as a backdrop that you will colorize, then run the `colorizeWithColor:` action on it. Remember to set the `colorBlendFactor` to 1.0.

Comment: This sounds like a very good idea / workaround that should fix my problem. Thanks, I will give this a try

Comment: Yep, definitely did it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
SKSpriteNode *bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:self.size];
bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.size.width/2, bg.size.height/2);
[self addChild:bg];    
SKAction *color1 = [SKAction colorizeWithColor:[SKColor orangeColor] colorBlendFactor:1 duration:5];
SKAction *color2 = [SKAction colorizeWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] colorBlendFactor:1 duration:10];
SKAction *color3 = [SKAction colorizeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] colorBlendFactor:1 duration:15];    
[bg runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[color1,color2,color3]]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for Swift4:**

```
let colorBackground = SKAction.colorize(with: SKColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1.0), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.25)

scene.childNode(withName: BackgroundCategoryName)!.run(colorBackground)
```

where BackgroundCategoryName is the SKSpriteNode for example:

```
let background = childNode(withName: BackgroundCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
```